# Who's stronger, Vados or Beerus?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

In Dragon Ball Super who's stronger, Beerus or Vados?
I'm up to date with the anime but I still don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well its definitely Vados. We know that Beerus himself told that Whis is stronger them him and when we were first introduced to Vados, I think Goku asked if she strong and it was stated that some time ago she was stronger then Whis too.

Also generally, as far as we know angels are taking care of gods of destruction and training them so it implies that they are usually stronger too.

"Vados is confident of her fighting skills. When telling Goku who was stronger between her and Whis, she claims to be superior but Whis objects to this. Vados wanted to test their power after Whis stated this. She can also be rather blunt and coy at times. Vados tells Goku that by looking at Champa's and Beerus' physiques, you can tell who's stronger."

http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Vados

Comment: This question was wrongly closed. In the manga it is stated that Vados is stronger than Wiss. And the movie and Akira Toriyama stated than Wiss is stronger than Beerus. So by transitive property it is stated than Vados is stronger than Beerus, which makes it not opinion based